# Limitar una consulta por el numero de hasMany laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

En un proyecto hecho en **Laravel 4.1** Tengo un Modelo llamado **OfertaUba** en donde se inscriben muchos **InscritosUba**, pero en la oferta hay un campo llamado **cupos** que se supone debe limitar la cantidad de inscritos, pero cuando consulto a la base de datos para traerme las ofertas necesito una forma de traerme solo las ofertas cuyo numero de inscritos no supere el valor en el campo cupos, pero no consigo manera de hacerlo, probe con

```
->has("inscritosuba","<","cupos")
```

pero no funciona, también intente con

```
->where(function($query){
    $query->has("inscritosuba","<",$query->first()->inscritosuba()->count());
});
```

Y tampoco funciona, hay alguna manera de hacer esto? Actualmente lo estoy consiguiendo con un foreach y comprobando cada elemento que trae la consulta y si tiene el número máximo de inscritos hago un unset() pero es realmente ineficiente y quisiera lograrlo directamente con la consulta, muchas gracias. Aqui les dejo los dos modelos:

El modelo oferta:

```
class OfertaUba extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'oferta_uba';
    protected $fillable = array('curso', 'nucleo', 'lapso', 'regimen', 'modalidad', 'turno', 'aula', 'dias', 'horas', 'cupos', 'facilitador', 'fecha_inicio', 'fecha_fin', 'fecha_apertura','fecha_cierre');

    public function inscritosuba(){
        return $this->hasMany('InscritosUba','id_oferta')->orderBy('cedula','asc');
    }

    public function facilitadores(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Facilitadores','facilitador');
    }

    public function modalidades(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Modalidad','modalidad');
    }

    public function nucleos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Nucleos','nucleo');
    }

    public function niveles(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Niveles','curso','Nivel');
    }

    public function regimenes(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Regimen','regimen');
    }

    public function lapsos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Lapso','lapso');
    }
}
```

Y el modelo de inscritos:

```
class InscritosUba extends Eloquent{

   protected $table = 'inscritos_uba';

   protected $fillable = array('cedula', 'curso', 'id_oferta', 'correo', 'telefono','pregunta_asocim','detalle_asocim');

   public function ofertauba(){
       return $this->belongsTo('OfertaUba','id_oferta');
   }

   public function estudiante(){
       max_execution_time();
       return $this->belongsTo('Estudiantes','cedula');
   }

   public function pagosuba(){
       return $this->hasMany('PagosUba','id_inscrito');
   }

   public function notaFinal(){
       max_execution_time();
       return $this->hasOne('Notas','CEDULA','cedula')->where('lapso','=',$this->ofertauba->lapso);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el método  `has()` está diseñado para recibir únicamente números enteros, entonces en este caso a pesar de ser un query relativamente sencillo (solo es reemplazar dicho entero por una columna de OfertaUba), creo que no sería posible, al menos no de esta forma.

Aquí una pequeña traza del código de `has()`:

```
public function has($relation, $operator = '>=', $count = 1, $boolean = 'and', Closure $callback = null)
{
    // ...

    return $this->addHasWhere(
        $hasQuery, $relation, $operator, $count, $boolean
    );
}
```

el método `addHasWhere()`:

```
protected function addHasWhere(Builder $hasQuery, Relation $relation, $operator, $count, $boolean)
{
    $hasQuery->mergeConstraintsFrom($relation->getQuery());

    return $this->canUseExistsForExistenceCheck($operator, $count)
            ? $this->addWhereExistsQuery($hasQuery->toBase(), $boolean, $not = ($operator === '<' && $count === 1))
            : $this->addWhereCountQuery($hasQuery->toBase(), $operator, $count, $boolean);
}
```

el método `addWhereCountQuery()`:

```
protected function addWhereCountQuery(QueryBuilder $query, $operator = '>=', $count = 1, $boolean = 'and')
{
    $this->query->addBinding($query->getBindings(), 'where');

    return $this->where(
        new Expression('('.$query->toSql().')'),
        $operator,
        is_numeric($count) ? new Expression($count) : $count,
        $boolean
    );
}
```

El problema está básicamente en el último método, al momento de agregar el Binding.

---

**Soluciones posibles**:

Estuve revisando como hacer una sola consulta por medio de Eloquent y la verdad no encontré cómo, a menos que otra persona nos muestre un mejor camino, solo se me ocurre:

- Escribir la consulta en "Raw"
- Hacer un override de alguno de los tres métodos implicados para que `has()` pueda aceptar una columna de tabla como parámetro.

---

Edición para agregar consulta "Raw":

Realicé una prueba con un escenario similar, y la consulta sería así (aunque me puedo equivocar en alguna pequeña apreciación):

```
    $sub = OfertaUba::withCount('inscritosuba');
    $ofertas = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
            ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
            ->whereColumn('inscritosuba_count', '<', 'cupos')
            ->get();
```

---

Edito de nuevo para mostrar la consulta, para que el OP la pueda recrear en la versión 4.1 de Laravel:

```
select * from (
    select "oferta_uba".*, (
        select count(*) from "inscritos_uba" where "oferta_uba"."id" = "inscritos_uba"."oferta_uba_id" and "inscritos_uba"."deleted_at" is null
    ) as "inscritos_count" from "oferta_uba" where "oferta_uba"."deleted_at" is null
) as sub where "inscritos_count" < "cupos"
```

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la respuesta, como harias la consulta en Raw? La verdad no soy muy habil en sql por eso uso eloquent

Comment: Por favor revisa lo que agregué a la respuesta.

Comment: El proyecto esta hecho en laravel 4.1 y no existe el metodo whitCount() :/

Comment: Debiste especificar eso en tu pregunta....

Comment: Si, ya edito la pregunta, disculpa las molestias

Comment: Realmente no tengo una respuesta para 4.1, es muy viejo y ya empleé bastante tiempo en resolver esto para 5.x. Más tarde te agrego el query "raw" y lo puedes generar con Eloquent.

Comment: Listo, tal vez me haya equivocado en algo al cambiar los nombres de las tablas, pero esa es la consulta.

Comment: ¿Finalmente fue resuelto este problema?